# Recommend a slideshow module that can create a display from a view?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

We have a design comp that looks like this:

[image]

We have a content type called `speaker`, which contains a file field that the headshot image is uploaded to. There are also several other fields, including an entity reference to another content type. What we'd like to do is be able to create a view that contains all the info we need and then have it formatted as a slideshow (where mousing over a single image brings up a div or something containing speaker name, company, etc.)

I've found several slideshow modules that are integrated with Views, but none of them seems to do quite what we need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the jCarousel module has Views support and produces a similar looking display: http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel

[image: jcarousel example]

It is also maintained by one the top Drupal contributors.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I have never been satisfied with any of the existing slideshow modules.

Typically, I use Views to render out the HTML I want.  Sometimes I use field output, but lately I have been using node output with a custom view mode.

The I use some custom CSS and JS to make the slideshow do exactly what I want.

Normally, I wrap all of this up in a custom block.

It may sound complicated, but it usually only takes a few hours to do all of this.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently pointed to Views + Views Slideshow + Views Slideshow: Galleria and I really dig it.